# Weird numbering system for theorems, definitions, propositions, etc

Tags: numbering, theorems, definition, abnt, abntex2

I am using many packages in my .tex file, I believe it is because of the abntex2 package that I am using for compliance with Brazilian ABNT standards that this problem is ocurring, not that as far as I know this is in the ABNT standards to begin with.

The problem is that the numering of Definitions, Theorems, Propositions and so on; appear to have a extra numbering index that is always zero and that is distinc from the chapter, section and local ordering of the def./theor./prop./etc. How do I solve this so that I eliminate this extra numbering?

Examples:

-> First Theorem of Chapter 2 before any section:

[image]

-> First Definition of Chapter 2 before any section:

[image]

-> First Definition of Chapter 2 section 1:

[image]

-> First Theorem of Chapter 2 section 2 (This one actually makes sense, perhaps the First Theorem of Chapter 2 before any section would also make sense if I called that section 0, but I would rather have that one as 2.1. instead of 2.0.1 ):

[image]

->Sixth Definition of Chapter 2 section 2 (First definition after The second theorem of Chapter 2 section 2, i.e. Theorem 2.2.2.):

[image]

-> First Definition of Appendix A, before any sections or theorems/prop.:

[image]

-> Third definition of Appendix A, before any sections, but after the first proposition of Appendix A (Proposition A.0.1.):

[image]

(ignore the coloring that is just from a marking that makes the background color of the page grey).

It seems that the Theorems and Propositions alter the numbering of the definitions that come after them placing a strange boilerplate numbering in the beguining and making them begin ordering themselfves again as 1,2,3,...
For me it would mekemore sense, and I would prefer, if these were numbered (in the cited order) as:

- Theorem 2.1.
- Definition 2.2.
- Definition 2.1.1.
- Theorem 2.2.1. (✓ Ok)

(Theorem 2.2.2. (✓ Ok))

- Definition 2.2.8.
- Definition A.1.

(Proposition A.3.)

- Definition A.4.

Here is a minimal example as was requested in the comments (please take a look in the numbering of the Defs/Theorems and ignore the contents that are just gibberish to fill space):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
0aaaa
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
0bbbb
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
0Th.aaaa
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
0cccc
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
0dddd
\end{definition}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{definition}
0eeee
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
0Th.bbbb
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
0ffff
\end{definition}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{definition}
1aaaa
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
1bbbb
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
1Th.aaaa
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
1cccc
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
1dddd
\end{definition}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{definition}
1eeee
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
1Th.bbbb
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
1ffff
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without a minimal example of code it's impossible to help.

Comment: I will put a minimal example in the question, it is quite easy, so please help me?

Comment: apparently it has to do with the [section] or [theorem] part of the definitions, but I don't know which to use to get the desired result.

Comment: Compare `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}` with `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[theorem]`. What do you conclude?

Comment: I conclude that this makes the lemma enviroment behave like the definition enviroment with 4 numbering indexes instead of 3, instead of the also flawed but less so than the theorem enviroment.

Comment: What I want is to have a mode in which i Have something like putting 
    `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`    `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}` 
   `\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}`    `\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}`    `\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}`  but that instead of puttting a 0 when it is placed before any section it just ignores the zero and shortens the index. That is to say, when once there would be Theorem 1.0.1. it becomes 1.1. while Theorem 1.1.1. keeps being 1.1.1.